# Spring jdbcTemplate is stuck at Fetching JDBC Connection

Tags: spring, log4j, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, apache-commons-dbcp

I am having issue with spring jdbcTemplate. It used to work fine but now it doesn't return any value neither error message. My table size has grown considerably large, around 35 million records which could be a reason for this.

But my main concern is that `jdbcTemplate` is not throwing any exception neither releasing the control to next line of code and my application breaks.
I would like the `jdbcTemplate` to release connection if for some reason it is unable to perform the query operation. Below is my code, data source details and log statements that I get from log4j after enabling debug logs. Nothing is logged after Fetching JDBC connection.

```
SqlRowSet oRs = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(strSql, new Object[] { Integer.valueOf(1) });
```

**Data Source** configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:4928/dbtest" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sendMail" class="com.app.SendMails">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="response" class="com.app.BuildResponses">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Logs:**

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Executing prepared SQL statement 
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you able to connect with other SQL clients (the command line client for example)?

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned that. My other queries execute fine before reaching this line of code where it fails.

Comment: try increasing the maxActive property to 100. It might be the case that your initial connections are taken by JDBC to do the test connections and/or other queries. And see if that is the case. I also would recommend you to fetch data in chunk so that it wont take much time to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the JDBC connection pool is exhausted and the thread is waiting for a connection ? Do you have other threads or transactions which use the same data source ?

To check if the connection pool is exhausted add

```
<property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
```

To your **dataSource** bean definition. You will get an exception if a connection can't be allocated within timeout which is 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

BasicDataSource waits forever when borrowing a connection from the pool unless you specify a timeout.

Comment: I added maxWait to properties. The issue still persist. What i am assuming is connection is not an issue here, its able to connect but taking time to execute the query. I added jdbcTemplate().setQueryTimeout(3) but it didn't help. My concern is jdbcTemplate is not logging anything after Fetching JDBC connection.

Comment: Then I would debug the problematic section of code and dive into Spring's JdbcTemplate code with debugger to detect which method inside JDBC template is blocking.

Comment: I also have the same issue. It is working in my development env. but not working in UAT setup. Development environment is windows and UAT is Linux.